# 'Windows Update Error Code 80092004' in Windows 7 64-bit SP1

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates

I get an "Update ErrorCode 80092004" in Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1 when 'repeatedly' attempting to 'Update'.

> Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3038314)
>   Download size: 42.7 MB

It even manually downloaded/failed to install.

Microsoft Fix it 50123 returns the following:

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2738.

The 'WindowsUpdateDiagnostic' Troubleshooting Pack Cabinet returned:

> Not fixed - 'Windows Update error 0x80070057(2015-04-30-T-03_52_41P)

I reported these:

> 'Not Fixed' - Service registration is missing or corrupt

...and these 'Unspecified' but two times:

> 'Fixed' - Problems installing recent updates

A few minutes later before I begin a check for updates the notes below read:

```
Most recent check for updates: Never
Updates were installed:        Never
You receive updates:           For Windows and other products from MS Update
```

...which now results with this:

> Windows could not search for new updates
>   An error occurred while checking for new updates for your computer.
>   Error(s) found:
>
> Code 80072EE2 Windows encountered an unknown error.

Which I'm now going to research.

There are other issues but as yet nothing more than occasional super slow but still able to get on to the Internet, etc.

Comment: 80092004 =  CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND (cat file is damaged) and 80072EE2 = ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT, so you have an internet connection issues.

Answer (score 1):

I just had that windows update error 80092004 and resolved it.

See

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-error-80092004/485d1cbd-b14f-46b2-bf51-6d6a8658ce9a

Install **KB4490628**

**https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb4490628**

Note- a related error I had earlier was see [Windows 7 Windows update error 80072EFE](https://superuser.com/questions/1631204/windows-7-windows-update-error-80072efe)     windows update  error 80072EFE resolved with KB3138612