# Windows 7 Windows update error 80072EFE

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have a HP PC. Recently, I have reset it, and it downgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 7. After the reset, I am trying to install windows updates. But when I try to search for new updates, I get the following error:

[image]

I did some research, and attempted all the solutions below with no success:

1. Enable and disable `Background Intelligent Transfer Service`, `Windows update`, and `Cryptographic Service` in `services.msc` at windows run
2. Clean the folder `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` and deleted the folder `C:\Windows\System32\catroot2`
3. Tried to install windows update [KB3138612](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3138612). In fact, I tried all the variant updates listed in the link. All of them result into `The update doesn't apply to your system`

I am really running out of ideas. What should I do in order to be able to install windows updates to my PC?

Here is a list of the updates installed on my PC so far. Sorry that it is in French
[image]

Comment: Windows 7 has already reached its end of life, its official support is over, Microsoft doesn't release updates for it anymore, I suggest you to download the latest Windows 10 20H2 iso file and do an inplace upgrade.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that had a lot of fluff. The update needed as you probably well know, ias the 612 update.. that's an update for windows update.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think the version you installed is too old to contact the Microsoft servers.

I suggest:

1. Follow the article
   [Windows 7: How to Check if Service Pack 1 is Installed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2352.windows-7-how-to-check-if-service-pack-1-is-installed.aspx)
   to see if SP1 is installed
2. If SP1 is not installed,
   [download](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB976932)
   it and install
3. Two updates are required for the next step. The first one
   below is sometimes sufficient, but installing both is safer:

   - [KB3138612 update](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3138612)
   - [KB3020369 update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/april-2015-servicing-stack-update-for-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2-437ee749-51e0-6265-be9e-73fbd115d315) (direct link to [Microsoft Update Cataloq](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3020369))
4. Download and install  KB3125574 the so-called
   [convenience rollup for Windows 7 SP1](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=3125574),
   which is a misnomer for the never-arriving SP2 service-pack.
   Even if Windows Update is working after the previous step,
   installing this roll-up is equivalent to a service-pack in that
   it clears up all the previously installed updates, just the same
   as a service pack, with a net gain in disk space. It will also be faster than installing separately all the updates that it contains.

Comment: This worked for me. THANK YOU

Comment: Has Microsoft shut down the update servers for Windows 7, because I followed all the steps in your answer and I don't get error `80072EFE` anymore but I still can't update Windows, it just hangs on checking for updates.

Comment: @Shayan: As Windows 7 is not supported any more, the situation might change from time to time. Basically unpredictable. The poster had a particular problem that resolved itself after applying my answer.

Comment: Just worked for me.

Comment: I had the same issue as OP, and followed these steps, and it got Windows Update working again for me. The first time I ran it after these steps, it took a long time at the first stage, "Searching for updates" or whatever, so it sort of looked frozen. But that's just because there were a lot of updates required - mine came back with ~70 required updates.

Comment: @SSilk: thanks for adding that bit, instructive and complements the answer. Was exactly what happened with me.

Comment: Step 3 worked for me. After that I had 194 critical updates. Went to step 4 and installed the roll-up. Now I'm restarting to see how many updates will be remaining. Working with a laptop that hasn't had an update in 10 years.

Comment: Worked for me! Step 4 took a while to install but worked fine. Also Windows prompts you to reboot after step 3, and it's probably best to do that before moving on to step 4.

Comment: I have archived the required update files (not SP1) here: https://archive.org/details/win7-error-80072EFE-updates

Comment: Posts here indicate that  KB3138612 is needed and certainly for me it was needed.  They may as well try and install that one first.   It's possible you are mistaken in thinking that  KB3020369 is needed?

Comment: According to [this article](https://bit.ly/3HOCxMg), KB3020369 is pre-requisite for the convenience rollup rather than to fix this error.

Comment: After applying all of the above updates, I'm no longer seeing the error and Update is functioning great. My legacy system is happy.

Comment: 3020369 failed with "not applicable to your system" or whatever; but 3138612 installed and so did the roll-up, and that all worked like a charm (Win 7 Pro SP1 machine that hasn't been updated since 2013, and suddenly found a purpose again as my oh-crap-I-just-spilled-a-gallon-of-Gatorade-on-my-laptop emergency backup plan, lol). Thanks!

Comment: I would really like to follow Step 2, but I'm prevented from this due to `ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING(0x80073701)` https://superuser.com/questions/1738422/windows-7-service-pack-1-cant-be-installed-error-sxs-assembly-missing0x80073

Comment: I can confirm that as of 12-2022 this works properly for Windows 7 Embedded Standard.

Comment: This REALLY work, as of 18/jan/2023. Tested on a new machine, installed from ISO Windows7, applied SP1, and (after it cannot windowsupdate, whatever, like que OP said, and after doing EXACTLY like described here, it started working PERFECTLY! Thank yo very much! THIS IS VALID FOR NEW 2023 INSTALLS

Answer (score 4):

Might I suggest that you use a program called WSUS offline to download all the Win7 updates and install them offline. I have used this program for a number of years, just to solve the sort of problem you're having. On first run, tell it which version of Win  you use and it will access MS and download all the appropriate updates. When it is finished, run the update installer and it will do its thing, rebooting as necessary. YMMV, but it has always worked like a champ for me, even when I was having to update dozens of machines.

Comment: Never came across this before, what a useful tool! Note that Version 11.9 is the last one that supports Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

Servicing update KB3020369 does not solve the issue. Perhaps is needed as a prerequisite, I'm not sure.

It should not harm to install; it did not require restart.

For me, KB3138612 *did* solve the issue.

Prior to KB3138612 installation, runas cmd.exe displayed the executable as unsigned. 
After installing, cmd.exe runas appears again as signed.

Note. KB3138612 does require restart.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Only KB3138612 is required to get Windows Update working again. There may be prerequisites. In my case, this worked on a stock install of 2008 R2 with SP1.

Comment: Yeah I doubt the KB3020369 is even a pre-requisite... You're right that it's KB3138612 that is needed. Infact the description for the 612 one says update for windows update. Clearly probably jst the 612 one is needed

Answer (score 1):

You say

> I have reset it, and it downgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 7

If windows 10 was activated on that machine previously you can just re-install Windows 10 and it will activate online as Microsoft will have recorded that motherboard in their database of valid Windows 10 machines. Since Windows 7 support has ended, MS may cut off their update servers for Windows 7 at any time. There are certainly not regular updates being supplied for Windows 7, and have not been for some time.

If you need installation media you can download it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
You may even be able to just directly update your Windows 7 to Windows 10 with an in place upgrade, keeping any of your existing files, and even most of your programs.

Comment: OP is asking how to run windows update on Windows 7, not how to update to Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

KB3138612 did solve the issue for me without any additional steps on restored Lenovo Win7 Home 64bit Intel system.

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3138612

Note- others have simce indicated this is actually the one needed.