# Windows7 error (0xc0000005) in many applications even after format and reinstall multiple times

Tags: windows, windows-7, partitioning

Windows7 SP1 x64

I had to format my PC and reinstall windows7 because of a small issue some days ago, i was able to do so without much problem.
Almost everything worked fine except for a small thing so i decided to format and reinstall windows again.
Now many software (even from microsoft) give an error 0xc0000005 when try to run it.

- [Software from microsoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMB8d.png)
- [Third party software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRmM1.png)

Applications like chrome don't show transparent icons when downloading, [all have a black square in the background, so there is definitely something weird going on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHoWx.png)

I tried to find the error in the event viewer, and it think [this is it, but not sure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETNOe.png)
When i re-downloaded the same exact software and saved it on C: [instead of D:, since it worked so i thought it was a disk error/corruption (even if most software except some DO work fine) but it was not the case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJVFV.png)

I tried the following solutions:

- Format system partition and reinstall windows 7 multiple times.
- Run sfc /scannow.
- [Test the ram memory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDTUW.png)
- Restore windows 7 (even if it's a new installation) to it's most previous point.
- [Do a disk check on D: unit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHs05.png)
- Disable DEP. (can't do this for microsoft software like C++ redistributables)

None worked or found a problem.

I am at my wits end, i tried everything and NOTHING works.
How can an OS suddenly fail to open files out of nowhere when it worked previous times it was installed?
Machines execute the exact same code, it is beyond logic and common sense that reinstalling a OS that had almost everything working fine a day ago just chose not to work properly out of the blue, no matter how many times re-install it!.
And it's even more illogical that it do not show any kind of error when try to examine the problem.

Comment: So you installed Windows 7 and all available updates and service packs before testing or just the plain version you have installer DVD for? Have you considered a test using Windows 10 or Linux just do make sure the hardware is really ok? Finally is there a reason to stick with Windows 7 as free upgrade to 10 is still possible?

Comment: I am going to try other versions of W7 but i refuse to go to W10 precisely because it's free. The user is the product, so it's full of sponsored malware (skype) and tracking telemetry/spyware.

Answer (score 0):

Well it does not seem like a disk error.
Try installing Windows 8.1 or 10 and if the applications work than it is clear that it is an operating system problem

If you try to call Microsoft they will just tell you are using an unsupported system but here is the trick try searching on Google for 'Windows thin pc' or 'Windows 7 embedded standard'. You will be surprised to know that these are official variations of windows 7 that are still being supported by Microsoft! There maybe some update that fixes your problem and if you call Microsoft and tell them your problem, they have no other option but to solve your problem.
I hope this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: Could this be a disk error after all? The following happened: I re-downloaded the C++ redistributables that were failing after download, ALL of them. They all worked and installed BUT seconds later when i clicked them again....error 0xc0000005. It makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

The Event Viewer error is not indicative of any issue and can be
safely ignored.
It comes from an error in the Windows 7 SP1 DVD/ISO creation process that caused a WMI registration to remain in the DVD/ISO.
Since this registration is designed to work only during the DVD/ISO
creation process, it fails to run on a live system and causes these
events.

If you want to prevent these events from getting,follow the steps mentioned
in the Microsoft article
[Event ID 10 is logged in the Application log after you install Service Pack 1 for Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/event-10-is-logged-in-application-log).

For correctly installing Windows 7, follow my steps from the post
[Windows 7 Windows update error 80072EFE](https://superuser.com/a/1632323/8672).
Then download and install any hardware drivers that were supplied by
the manufacturer of your computer.

If you have done the above steps and the problems still arrive, I would
consider the possibility of a hardware issue. I gather that this computer
came with Windows 7, so is pretty old, so a hardware issue is possible
after a demanding operation such as installing Windows.

I suggest running
[MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)
overnight, for as many passes as you the time.
Publish online (DropBox, OneDrive etc.) the HTML report file for us
to have a look at.
This tests more than just the memory; also testing incidentally
the CPU and the memory controller.

Comment: Could this be a disk error? The following happened: I re-downloaded the C++ redistributables that were failing after download, ALL of them. They all worked and installed BUT seconds later when i clicked them again....error 0xc0000005. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Also, i downloaded memtest, used the usb disk image application, made an image and restarted PC (just wanted to restart PC)...when clicked the usb disk image application in the desktop...suddenly error 0xc0000005.

Comment: This starts sounding like a hardware problem.